# Share bitmaps between activities xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, android-bitmap, android-internal-storage

Good day.

In my code I send a byte array from one activity to the next with Putextra and GetByteArray to display a Image on two activities. It works until I jump between activities for a certain amount of times. Then I get an error saying Java.lang.OutOfMemoryerror . Is there a way I can save the Bitmap to my internal storage from my first activity and then decode it from my internal storage in my second activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to put anything more than short pieces of text in the Putextra command. You should save the image to the internal storage of the device and then send the file path (using the Putextra).

Here is something to get you started in a better direction: [How to save an image to Internal Storage and then show it on another activity](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15661/how-to-save-an-image-to-internal-storage-and-then-show-it-on-another-activity)